# Installing old version of memcached gem in Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems, docker-compose

I have to maintain the old Ruby on Rails 2.3.17 application that works on Ruby 1.9.3 and wanted to move development to the Docker for OS X (Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6) but with the main goal - to have folder on the host in order to avoid reinstalling gems whenever I start new container. I tried to use Docker volume that uses host directory and install all gems there. With following Dockerfile

```
FROM zedtux/ruby-1.9.3
RUN apt-get update -qq \
&& apt-get install -y \
   build-essential \
   libmysqlclient-dev \
   libxml2-dev \
   libxslt-dev \
   libsasl2-2 \
   libsasl2-dev \
   nodejs \
   git \
&& apt-get clean autoclean \
&& apt-get autoremove -y \
&& rm -rf \
   /var/lib/apt \
   /var/lib/dpkg \
   /var/lib/cache \
   /var/lib/log

VOLUME /app
VOLUME /bundler-cache

RUN echo "---\ngem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" >> ~/.gemrc

WORKDIR /app
```

and docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /Users/bosko/central_bundle_storage/app-gems:/bundler-cache
      - ${PWD}:/app
    environment:
      GEM_HOME: /bundler-cache
      GEM_PATH: /bundler-cache
      BUNDLE_PATH: /bundler-cache
      PATH: /bundler-cache/bin:$PATH
```

after building and starting container with:

```
docker-compose run --rm web bash
```

I am installing bundler and gems with:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Most of gems that have to be built due to native extensions (i.e. nokogiri, etc.) install properly but I have a problem with memcached gem. Building gem fails with the following error:

```
    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.                                                                                  [7/1778]

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:7: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
Touching all files so autoconf doesn't run.
find . | xargs touch
Configuring libmemcached.
env CFLAGS='-fPIC -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -g -O2 -fstack-protector
--param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC' LDFLAGS='-fPIC -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
-L/build/buildd/ruby1.9.1-1.9.3.484/debian/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/build/buildd/ruby1.9.1-1.9.3.484/debian/lib
-rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/usr/lib' ./configure --prefix=/bundler-cache/gems/memcached-1.4.6/ext --without-memcached --disable-shared --disable-utils
--disable-dependency-tracking CC="gcc"  2>&1
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... configure: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!
Check your system clock
extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
extconf.rb:35:in `run': 'env CFLAGS='-fPIC -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -g -O2
-fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC' LDFLAGS='-fPIC -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
-L/build/buildd/ruby1.9.1-1.9.3.484/debian/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/build/buildd/ruby1.9.1-1.9.3.484/debian/lib
-rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/usr/lib' ./configure --prefix=/bundler-cache/gems/memcached-1.4.6/ext --without-memcached --disable-shared --disable-utils
--disable-dependency-tracking CC="gcc"  2>&1' failed (RuntimeError)
from extconf.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in check_libmemcached'
from extconf.rb:50:in `chdir'
from extconf.rb:50:in `block in check_libmemcached'
from extconf.rb:49:in `chdir'
from extconf.rb:49:in `check_libmemcached'
from extconf.rb:69:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /bundler-cache/gems/memcached-1.4.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /bundler-cache/gems/memcached-1.4.6/ext/gem_make.out
```

Error is caused by following line in extconf.rb file of memcached gem:

```
run("env CFLAGS='-fPIC #{LIBM_CFLAGS}' LDFLAGS='-fPIC #{LIBM_LDFLAGS}' ./configure --prefix=#{HERE} --without-memcached --disable-shared --disable-utils --disable-dependency-tracking #{$CC} #{$EXTRA_CONF} 2>&1", "Configuring libmemcached.")
```

However if is go to `/bundler-cache/gems/memcached-1.4.6/ext/libmemcached-0.32` folder while I'm still on the container's bash and execute expanded version of above command:

```
env CFLAGS='-fPIC -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC' LDFLAGS='-fPIC -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/build/buildd/ruby1.9.1-1.9.3.484/debian/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/build/buildd/ruby1.9.1-1.9.3.484/debian/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L/usr/lib' ./configure --prefix=/bundler-cache/gems/memcached-1.4.6/ext --without-memcached --disable-shared --disable-utils --disable-dependency-tracking CC="gcc"  2>&1
```

everything goes well without any problem. Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how can it be fixed either by fixing gem installation or proper volume mounting if that is the problem?

Comment: `checking whether build environment is sane... configure: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!` weird clock issues on the build machine?

Comment: Yes it looks like that except it is not neither separate machine nor virtual machine but Docker container.

Comment: Yes, but there is still the concept of time in the docker container.

Comment: Except that expanded command executed directly from the shell passes. Problem is obviously in invoking that command from Ruby.